# mysql mirroring

Tags: mysql-5.6, mirroring

I have 2 mysql server 5.6.34 running, one on aws RDS other locally. Is it possible to set up mirroring from RDS to local one? I know that later version like 8 support replication and mirroring via tools but migration to newer mysql is not an option for me..

Comment: if you canreach the aws server via ssh  you can always enable replication https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html